# known vs recognizable

Tags: adjectives

Which of the following answer is correct?

```
Laura was worried. She was not in a ____ area any more. She was lost...
a) common
b) known
c) recognizable
d) intimate
```

Thanks!

Comment: "she was not on familiar grounds anymore," which can be used both literally and figuratively.

Comment: When discovering unknown areas, you may feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @Elian - yes, but 'ground' (*singular*), no?

Comment: @Dan Indeed, it's heaps more idiomatic... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+familiar+ground%2Con+familiar+grounds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20familiar%20ground%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20familiar%20grounds%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yes, familiar is the original word used, but it is required to find another word that is closest in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Of all the options listed, I think *recognizable* is the best fit:

> able to be recognized or **identified from previous encounters** or knowledge

([Oxford American Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recognizable))

Laura couldn't recognize the area or surroundings any longer and realized she was lost. Therefore:

*Laura was worried. She was not in a **recognizable area** any more. She was lost...*